# Names with commas needs spaces added before first name

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv

I have been working on this project for a couple months - taking some generated xls and xlsx documents and using a combo of the csv module and pandas (python) to rearrange the whole order of the data so it will be appropriate for manual upload to a system that requires a certain data order for correct import.

no stress. There are several different documents with their own original structure as well as many templates for the import. Besides the data rearranging, I have also needed to add some internal codes to some of the documents that we need for local student work management and rename some columns to match the import requirements. I have all this working, but all my efforts to code something that takes student names and instructor names, currently listed as [lastname,firstname], NEED to be [lastname, firstname] with a **SPACE** added in the name after the comma before the first line.

I have messed around with a for loop using regex and something as simple as

```
df.replace(',', ', ', regex=True)
```

OR

```
df["Column Name"].str.replace(',', ', ') (which I think is way wrong, but tried it anyway)
```

What else might I try to accomplish what I would think of as being simple. Nothing seems to be working. I am running the script, I get no errors, and yet this change is not being made. I have looked all over stackoverflow, but am not having success.

thank you in advance

Comment: So many words, so little really useful information. Please check [ask]. Show [mre], incl. sample data. Check [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632)

Comment: You might just need to set the  default `inplace=False` argument to `inplace=True`

Comment: Also, both your code snippets don't work inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to ensure there is always just one space:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = [['flintstone,fred'], ['flintstone, wilma'], ['rubble,     barney']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name'])
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(', *', ', ', regex=True)

print(df)
```

Giving you:

```
                Name
0   flintstone, fred
1  flintstone, wilma
2     rubble, barney
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace will return a new dataframe, if you are doing other operation on that `df` try:

```
df = df.replace(',', ', ')
```

Otherwise try to add more line of your code to show what you do after the replace operation.

Comment: thanks Martin Evans, your suggestion was perfect.